# Application of dominated convergence theorem- find limit

Tags: lebesgue-integral

Find (with justification)
$$ 
\lim_{n\to \infty}  \int_0^n (1+x/n)^{-n}\log(2+\cos(x/n))\,dx
$$

Comment: See [this tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to format math properly.  Note the changes that I have made for future reference.

Comment: What have you tried here?  The usual approach is to use dominated convergence.  Does that apply here?  Can you find a bounding function?

Comment: Thank you for the edit. I am new at this.
 The function $$(1+x/n)^{-n} $$ is bounded by the constant function 1. However, this constant function is not integrable as n approaches infinity...

Answer (score 1):

Since $0<x<n$ it follows that $0<\dfrac{x}{n}<1$ and hence $\log(2+\cos(\dfrac{x}{n}))\leq\log3$.

Now $(1+\dfrac{x}{n})^{-n}=(1+\dfrac{x}{n})^{(n/x)(-x)}\leq2^{-x}$

So your dominating function is $3^{-x}\log 3$.

Now $(1+x/n)^{-n}\log(2+\cos(x/n))\to e^{-x}\log3$ so by Dominated Convergence Theorem,the integral converges to $\log3$.

Comment: Please, are you sure that $ (1+\dfrac{x}{n})^{-n} \leq 3^{-x}$, for $0<x<n$. If I try $x=\sqrt{2}$, $n=2$, I don't find your inequality. Thanks.

Comment: I am sorry, it should be $2$ instead of $3$. Typo!!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** You may observe that
$$
\left(1+\frac x n \right)^{-n}\leq e^{-x}, \quad x\geq0, n \in \mathbb{N}^*,
$$ and
$$
\log (2+ \cos (x/n)) \leq \log (2+ |\cos (x/n)|) \leq \log (2+1)=\log 3
$$ thus
$$
\mathbf{1}_{\large [0,n]}(x)\:\left(1+\frac x n \right)^{-n}\log (2+ \cos (x/n))\:\leq  \mathbf{1}_{\large [0,\infty)}(x)\: e^{-x} \:\log 3
$$
and then use the dominated convergence theorem to conclude.